# JAVA - How to make a installer for my software?

Tags: java, installation

How to make a java version installer for my software(java swing app)?

The installer will copy a jar(Launcher) file and a folder with sound and images file in the installer to the user's desktop and AppDate folder.

My problem is how to "know" the user's name so I can copy the file to the user's Desktop and AppData folder and how to copy the file..

Can someone help me. Thank

==Sorry for My Bad English==

Comment: Why not use something like IzPack: http://izpack.org/

Comment: I want to make my OWN installer

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? Writing an installer (never mind a cross platform one) is a non-trivial task.

Comment: I can see it now, he writes an installer and never gets around to writing an uninstaller, or does so and bugs delete important files on the computer. Such hubris.

Answer (score 3):

Java Web Start is your best option.  It handles everything, and it supports custom installers for things like setting up application data.

If your data files never change, you probably should bundle them in your .jar file and access them using `Class.getResource`, rather than copying them to a user's application data directory.

Using Java Web Start usually doesn't require writing any code.  You just create a short XML file, give it a .jnlp extension, and put it on a web server with your .jar file.  It usually looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE jnlp PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc//DTD JNLP Descriptor 6.0.10//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/JNLP-6.0.10.dtd">
<jnlp version="1.6"
      codebase="http://www.example.com/myapp/"
      href="MyApp.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>MyApp</title>
        <homepage href="http://www.example.com/myapp/"/>
        <description>My application</description>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>

    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>

    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="MyApp.jar" main="true"/>
    </resources>

    <application-desc/>
</jnlp>
```

More details can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html).

Comment: Usually it is not necessary to write any code.  Updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using System.getEnv("APPDATA"). This should return APPDATA folder, system independent.

Comment: Thank. How about how to copy file?

Comment: How to copy files from package in my project? From jeremy.installer.resources.music.something.ogg to the user's appdate folder("\AppData\Jeremy\resources.music.something.ogg")?

Comment: Not sure about that, I'm sorry.